# PHP simple_html_dom get element by contents

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use simple_html_dom to get an element by it's contents. The reason for this is that I'm scraping a page that has contents like:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Variable: </dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
    <dt>Another variable> </dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
</dl>
```

Now I want to parse certain variables and their values, so I need to do a

```
$html->find(dt[contains=Variable: ])
```

Or something like that, if you know what I mean. Is this possible?

Comment: there no built-in function for that, find filters work only for attributes nothing else so you need to foreach of all and then filter them on your own

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know. I managed to solve the problem per your suggestion by getting all dt-dd combinations, putting them all in an array, and then using the ones I need. Using the `next_sibling()` selector, I was able to make sure I get the dd that belongs to the dt ;-).  `foreach($html->find('dt') as $prop){ $array[$prop->plaintext]= $prop->next_sibling()->plaintext; }`

Comment: Put your new code in an answer and accept it as best answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kazz, I got the idea to just loop through all `dt` and put them all in an associative array together with the values from the `dd`s. Thanks!

```
foreach($html->find('dt') as $prop){ 
    $array[$prop->plaintext]= $prop->next_sibling()->plaintext; 
}
```